# Sybase hash row

Tags: hash, md5, sybase

I need to get the checksum of a table row wise. In PostgreSQL I can achieve it using the below query

```
SELECT col1, col2, md5(textin(record_out(table))) FROM table;
```

I am trying to achieve the same using Sybase hash. But the hash function can be applied for column wise only. So is it possible to hash the entire row in Sybase?

Comment: Which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? If this is ASE 15+ there is `hash()` and `hashbytes()`, with the latter allowing for multiple columns (eg, all columns in the table?) to be hashed together; see [hashbytes()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/blocks139.htm)

Comment: I am using SQLAnywhere 11. hashbytes() is not supported. Now I manually append columns and pass it to hash() which is working. In postgres the record_out() returns the complete row as a cstring. Trying to find a similar solution in Sybase.

Comment: the (obvious?) problem will be finding functions that perform **exactly** the same in both postgres and SQLAnywhere, ie, they have to pass the same exact data stream to the md5 hashing process; I'm wondering ... what if you replace the `textin(record_out())` call with the same appended column clause you're using in SQLAnywhere? (the idea being to pass the same exact appended column data stream to `md5()` and `hash()`)?

Comment: I got a situation where i have to use both Sybase and Postgres. The checksum generated from both the database should be same if the row matches. Appended columns in Postgres works. There will be multiple tables and I don't want to append columns for each table.

Comment: could you write a custom function to append the columns for you?  if the appended columns approach gives you the same hash then that may be the best you can accomplish; fwiw, in the past I've tried coming up with a hashing solution (for data verification) across Sybase/ASE, Oracle and HANA, w/ the net result being that there's nothing out-of-the-box the same re: hashing when it comes to the different RDBMS products so the user is left to their imagination/ingenuity ...

Comment: yes, custom function should be the right choice. The record_out() in Postgres adds double quotes if there is space in the data. So this will also change the checksum. Thank you very much for you help:)